# How to exclude some characters from the text matched group?

Tags: python, regex

I am going to match two cases: 123456-78-9, or 123456789. My goal is to retrieve 123456789 from either case, ie to exclude the '-' from the first case, no need to mention that the second case is quite straightforward.

I have tried to use a regex like `r"\b(\d+(?:-)?\d+(?:-)?\d)\b"`, but it still gives '123456-78-9' back to me.

what is the right regex I should use? Though I know do it in two steps: 1) get three parts of digits by regex 2) use another line to concat them, but I still prefer a regex so that the code is more elegant.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! Python here. I am exploring if it is possible to get 123456789 with calling re.finditer() once, without other codes to manipulate the captured groups, like concatting. So I dont quite understand how to use \1\2\3 in the regex for the purpose?

Comment: For regex replacement, you'd use `re.Sub()` instead of `re.finditer()`. I added a Python example to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put the numbers parts in capturing groups and then replace the entire match with just the captured groups.

Try something like:

```
\b(\d+)-?(\d+)-?(\d)\b
```

..and replace with:

```
\1\2\3
```

Note that the two non-capturing groups you're using are redundant. `(?:-)?` = `-?`.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FdSxAK/2).

**Python example:**

```
import re

regex = r"\b(\d+)-?(\d+)-?(\d)\b"

test_str = ("123456-78-9\n"
            "123456789")
subst = "\\1\\2\\3"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

**Output:**

```
123456789
123456789
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/NTW81652).

Comment: @Cuteufo re.finditer() is used to _find matches_. It can't change the content of the matches. To do that, you need to "find and replace" (which is what re.sub() does). Generally, you can't expect the "find" method to magically do the work of the "find and replace" method; the later exist for a reason.

Comment: That's why I asked to 'exclude' the '-' in original post, because I have used re.finditer() to handle all my cases, including the special ones in question. Anyway, you, along with many other guys, confirmed that it is not possible, and I would like to take your advice and change my route. Thanks everyone, and I will choose Ahmed's reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use   `r'(\d{6})(-?)(\d{2})\2(\d)'`
Then Join groups 1, 3 and 4, or replace using `"\\1\\3\\4"`

Will only match these two inputs:

123456-78-9, or 123456789

It's up to you to put boundary conditions on it if needed.

https://regex101.com/r/ceB10E/1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do here would be to first use `re.sub` to remove all non digit characters from the input.  Then, use an equality comparison to check the input:

```
inp = "123456-78-9"
if re.sub(r'\D', '', inp) == '123456789':
    print("MATCH")
```

Edit: If I misunderstood your problem, and instead the inputs could be anything, and you just want to match the two formats given, then use an alternation:

```
\b(?:\d{6}-\d{2}-\d|\d{9})\b
```

Script:

```
inp = "123456-78-9"
if re.search(r'\b(?:\d{6}-\d{2}-\d|\d{9})\b', inp):
    print("MATCH")
```

Comment: This assumes that the input is guaranteed to be in the right format (which could be the case).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I don't understand your comment.

Comment: This will still return true if the input is something like `--123$$45&&6-78-9`. Also, the output could be unknown beforehand. `123456789` could just be an example.

Comment: But remember, the OP is doing this from a Python script, for a use case where there are only two types of inputs (read the actual question).

Comment: I did read it :) The OP said they need to _match_ two cases, not that the input is guaranteed to be in one of those two formats. I could be wrong though and the OP could've actually meant the latter. It's just not clear at this point, IMO. That's all :)

Comment: My bad that I should have put it more clear. The input is in one of the two formats, and my purpose is to get 123456789 no matter which input was given, and I don't want to have additional codes to concat 123456, 78, 9. Thanks.

Comment: @Cuteufo Then my answer should cover your requirements.